# Alternative to DataSourceRequest

Tags: kendo-ui

There is `DataSourceRequest` class in KendoUI framework. It has `Filters` collection that allows to get filtering `Expressions` for each filter configured in grid. Is there alternative class to `DataSourceRequest` that contains all the grid data in "plain", not parsed format, without ability to build expressions but with all the form data "as is"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class built-in. You can however easily get the raw data from the Request object.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a better idea to override Telerik's DataSourceRequest model binder to implement the functionality that you want.